# Cout shows just dark screen in console

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct, cout

Writing "Snake Game" for my exams. I decided to give user choice of field size, and theoreticaly, on this stage it must show something, but function "Graphics" show nothing but dark screen.
 I suspect, problem can be  when Graphics refering to struct height and width definitions, maybe someway it doesn't see that i changed those definitions, and counts it as zero and zero, so size of field is zero and zero respectively... Anyway i dunno, can somebody help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool GameOver;

struct GameData
{
    int x{ 0 };
    int y{ 0 };
    int Width;
    int Height;
    int AppleX;
    int AppleY;
    int Score;

};

enum SnakeDirection {Stop = 0, Up, Down, Left, Right};
SnakeDirection Way;

void EnterFieldSize() 
{
    GameData GMD;
     int Width{ 0 };
     int Height{ 0 };
    std::cout << "Enter field size (Min 10, Max 100): \n";
    std::cout << "Width: "; std::cin >> Width;
    std::cout << "Height: "; std::cin >> Height;
     GMD.Width = Width;
     GMD.Height = Height;
    if (Width < 10 || Width > 100) //Если ширина меньше 10 или больше 100, повторить ввод
    {
        std::cout << "Unaccetable width! Enter again:\n ";
        return EnterFieldSize();
    }
    if (Height < 10 || Height > 100)
    {
        std::cout << "Unaccetable height! Enter again:\n ";
        return EnterFieldSize();
    }
    return;

}
void Settings() 
{
    EnterFieldSize();
    GameData GMD;
    Way = Stop; 
    GMD.x = rand() % GMD.Width; и
    GMD.y = rand() % GMD.Height;
    GMD.AppleX = rand() % GMD.Height; 
    GMD.AppleY = rand() % GMD.Width;
    GMD.Score = 0 ;
    return;
}

void GameLogic()
{

}

void Graphics()   //This part doesn't show
{
    GameData GMD;
    system("cls");

    for (int i{ 0 }; i < GMD.Width; i++) //Upper border
    {
        std::cout << "#";
    }

    for (int i{ 0 }; i < GMD.Height; i++) //Side borders
    {
        for (int q{ 0 }; q < GMD.Width; q++)
        {
            if (q == 0 || q == GMD.Width)
                std::cout << "#"; std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < GMD.Width; i++) //Lower border
    {
        std::cout << "#";
    }
    return ;
}

void Controller()
{

}




int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to \"Snake\"\n";
    Settings();
    while (!GameOver)

    {
        Graphics(); // THis moment, console just dark screen
        GameLogic();
        Controller();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For better screen control you'll want to use a "curses"-type library, not just `std::cout`.

Comment: You have a `return ; std::cout<< std::endl;` Note that the cout after the return will never be reached. Once execution hits return its done.

Comment: When it says "add more explanation" don't just put in junk text. **Explain more**.

Comment: `GMD.Width` and `GMD.Height` in `Settings()` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You have several variables called `GMD`. One in `Settings`, one in `Graphics`, one in `EnterFieldSize`. These are all different variables.

Two variables in different functions are different variables even if they have the same name. Your `Settings` function is changing one variable but your `Graphics` function is using a completely different variable.

You should declare one `GMD` variable in `main` and pass this as a reference parameter to all the functions that need to use it.

You probably need to do some reading on C++ fundamentals. Parameter passing is a basic skill in pretty much any programming language, as is the concept of *variable scope*.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you set the instantiate GMD, put height and width and you return nothing. You can solve this by setting the method from void to GMD and than return that instance of GMD in the graphics function

A second option is to create a class with a variable GMD and use the same code